# Groovy ConfigObject add map to existing config and write back

Tags: groovy

I am new to ConfigObject. I am planning to use it for storing the results of an analytics job. However occasionally I might need to add new configuration field, and I am having a difficult time adding variables to ConfigObject. So I decided to add a map instead. But that is not getting formatted correctly, resulting in error while reading back. I am not sure how to proceed..

```
config.groovy file
-------------------
"serverX" {
        var {
                low=-12.89
                maybe_low=1.65
                maybe_high=40.45
                high=55
        }
}


rest of Script
----------------------
ConfigObject conf = new ConfigSlurper("development").parse(new File("config.groovy").toURI().toURL());
System.out.println(conf);

// New object to add
def var_stuff = ['low' : 0] + ['maybe_low' : 0] + ['maybe_high' : 0] +  ['high' : 0]
def var_object = ['var' : var_stuff]
def final_var_object = ['ServerY' : var_object]

def new_config_object = final_var_object as ConfigObject

conf.merge(new_config_object)

def file1 = new File('newconfig.groovy')
file1.withWriter('UTF-8') { writer -> 
    conf.writeTo(writer)
}
```

But the result turns out to be

```
serverX {
        var {
                low=-12.89
                maybe_low=1.65
                maybe_high=40.45
                high=55
        }
    }
serverY=["var":["low":0, "maybe_low":0, "maybe_high":0, "high":0]]
```

I did consider doing the following

```
ConfigObject conf_new = new ConfigObject();

conf_new."ServerY".tukey.low = 0
conf_new."ServerY".tukey.maybe_low = 0
conf_new."ServerY".tukey.maybe_high = 0

conf.merge(conf_new)
```

Which works great. But since "ServerY" is a variable for me, I cannot write such manual statements.

Any hints?

---

EDIT: 5th March 2016
As per Emmanuel's recommendation, i tried the following

```
def server = 'ServerY'
def more = [
    (server): [
        var: [
            low: 0,
            maybe_low: 0,
            maybe_high: 0,
            high: 0
        ]
    ]
]

conf.putAll(more)

def obj1_temp = conf as Map
System.out.println(obj1_temp)
/* which looks like this:
{ServerX={var={low=-12.89, maybe_low=1.65, maybe_high=40.45, high=55}}, ServerY={var={low=0, maybe_low=0, maybe_high=0, high=0}}}
*/
def file1 = new File('app/tasks/newconfig.groovy')
file1.withWriter('UTF-8') { writer -> 
    conf.writeTo(writer)
}
```

However output in the file is still similar as before :-(

```
ServerX {
        var {
                low=-12.89
                maybe_low=1.65
                maybe_high=40.45
                high=55
        }
}
ServerY=["var":["low":0, "maybe_low":0, "maybe_high":0, "high":0]]
```

which doesn't parse properly when reading back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `putMap()` to add the `Map` entries to the `ConfigObject`.

```
import groovy.util.ConfigSlurper

def content = '''
"serverX" {
        var {
                low=-12.89
                maybe_low=1.65
                maybe_high=40.45
                high=55
        }
}
'''

def conf = new ConfigSlurper("development").parse(content) // Using a String for demonstration purposes
def server = 'ServerY'
def more = [
    (server): [
        var: [
            low: 0,
            maybe_low: 0,
            maybe_high: 0,
            high: 0
        ]
    ]
]

conf.putAll(more)

// A test showing it works.
assert conf as Map == [
    serverX:[
        var:[
            low:-12.89,
             maybe_low:1.65, 
             maybe_high:40.45, 
             high:55]
         ], 
     ServerY:[
         var:[
             low:0, 
             maybe_low:0, 
             maybe_high:0, 
             high:0
          ]
      ]
]
```

### Update

So, `putAll()` didn't work as I expected. Here's the solution:

```
import groovy.util.ConfigSlurper
import groovy.util.ConfigObject

def content = '''
"serverX" {
        var {
                low=-12.89
                maybe_low=1.65
                maybe_high=40.45
                high=55
        }
}
'''

def mergeConfig = { configObject, server, map ->
    configObject.merge new ConfigObject().with {
        def var = getProperty(server).getProperty('var')

        map.each { key, value ->
            var.put(key, value)
        }

        delegate        
    }

    configObject
}

def conf = new ConfigSlurper("development").parse(content) // Using a String for demonstration purposes
conf = mergeConfig(conf, 'ServerY', [low: 0, maybe_low: 0, maybe_high: 0, high: 0])
```

You can now call `mergeConfig()` continuously to merge *configurations*. In this example, `mergeConfig()` is a Closure, but it would work as a method also.

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel for your understanding. I edited my post with your suggestion. However, when it is written to file, the format is still not appropriate. So I can't read it back.